# filename with special characters are not working as expected aws s3 presignedurl

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, pre-signed-url, aws-sdk-net

i am trying to get a presigned url for a file(**`Royal Groups & Rosters-40052692020900-21894108859110.xlsx`**)

```
        string uploadObjectPath = "Royal Groups & Rosters-40052692020900-21894108859110.xlsx";
        BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
        string preSignedURL = string.Empty;
        s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
        GetPreSignedUrlRequest request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Verb = HttpVerb.PUT,
            Key = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(uploadObjectPath),
            ContentType = contentType,
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
        };

        preSignedURL = s3Client.GetPreSignedURL(request);
```

but in the presigned url the filename was breaking after `&(ampersand)` and replacing the rest with `_(underscore)`

I have seen aws docs saying to handle special characters([likely need to be URL encoded or referenced as HEX](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html))

so i have changeed

`Key = uploadObjectPath` to `Key = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(uploadObjectPath)`

But with **System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode** also it is breaking(Royal%2BGroups%2B?X-Amz-Expires=1800&....).

Is that wrong? If yes then how do we handle these special characters..

Thanks

Comment: "...it is not working." Very broad statement. Perhaps more detail?

Comment: @Barns, still the returned presigned url is breaking after & and returing like this(//abc.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/users%2F200%2Femailattachments%2FRoyal%2BGroups%2B?X-Amz-Expires=1800&X...)